# Why do I get a huge batch of data at once instead of small 4 bytes pieces one after the other?

Tags: embedded

I have written a program which sends  4 bytes and a terminator \n byte, over and over in an endless loop. The full code is shown below.

To transfer data I use an FTDI cable - the datasheet is shown below.

I am connecting my EFR32FG14 controller and in MATLAB I am defining the port as shown below.

The communication is done using the TX RX GND shown in the diagram below.

We have LF which is \n and I defined a callback function to see the 4 byte data  each time MATLAB sees \n. The MATLAB callback function is shown below.

```
function callbackSerial(ser,~)
val=fgets(ser);
dec2hex(uint8(val))
end
```

But MATLAB is not reacting to \n at all. I don't get a live stream of small bits, instead I get a large delay and a huge block of data on the terminal as shown below.

Where did I go wrong?

https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/163/DS_C232HD_UART_CABLE-4313.pdf

```
    sObject=serial('COM4','BaudRate',115200,'TimeOut',10,'Terminator','LF')
sObject.BytesAvailableFcn={@callbackSerial};
fopen(sObject)
```

[image]
[image]

```
*******************************
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "em_usart.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "em_emu.h"
#include "bsp.h"
#include "bsp_trace.h"


uint8_t received_flag=0;//
// Receive data buffer
uint8_t buffer;
uint8_t tx_buffer=0x6F;
uint8_t tx_buffer_new=0x06;


void USART0_RX_IRQHandler(void)
{
    received_flag=1;
  // Get the character just received
  buffer = USART0->RXDATA;

  switch (buffer)
      {
        case 'a':

            tx_buffer_new=0x4F;
        break;

        case 'b':
            tx_buffer_new=0x62;
        break;

        case 'c':
                    tx_buffer_new=0x63;
         break;

        default:

        break;

      }//end switch
  // Clear the requesting interrupt before exiting the handler
  USART_IntClear(USART0, USART_IF_RXDATAV);
}



int main(void)
{
  uint32_t i;

  // Chip errata
  CHIP_Init();
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_GPIO, true);
  CMU_ClockEnable(cmuClock_USART0, true);


  //EFR32fg14 LOC2 page 157 data sheet TX P0
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA,2, gpioModePushPull, 1);

//EFR32fg14 LOC2 page 157 data sheet RX P2
  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA,3, gpioModeInput, 0);

  GPIO_PinModeSet(gpioPortA, 5, gpioModePushPull, 1);


  // Default asynchronous initializer (115.2 Kbps, 8N1, no flow control)
  USART_InitAsync_TypeDef init = USART_INITASYNC_DEFAULT;

  // Configure and enable USART0
  USART_InitAsync(USART0, &init);
  //datasheet page 157 location2  rx portA pin3(P2) ,tx port A pin2(P0)
  USART0->ROUTELOC0 = USART_ROUTELOC0_RXLOC_LOC2 | USART_ROUTELOC0_TXLOC_LOC2;
  USART0->ROUTEPEN |= USART_ROUTEPEN_TXPEN | USART_ROUTEPEN_RXPEN;


  // Enable NVIC USART sources
  NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART0_RX_IRQn);
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART0_RX_IRQn);
  //enabling TX interrupt made problems
  //NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(USART0_TX_IRQn);
  //NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART0_TX_IRQn);



  while (1)
  {

      if (received_flag==1)
      {
          USART_Tx(USART0,0x2F);
          USART_Tx(USART0,tx_buffer_new);
          USART_Tx(USART0,0x8F);
          USART_Tx(USART0,0x3F);
          USART_Tx(USART0,'\n');
          tx_buffer=tx_buffer_new;
          received_flag=0;
      }
      else
      {
                  USART_Tx(USART0,0x2F);
                  USART_Tx(USART0,tx_buffer_new);
                  USART_Tx(USART0,0x8F);
                  USART_Tx(USART0,0x3F);
                  USART_Tx(USART0,'\n');

      }
      for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
      {
           GPIO_PinOutSet(gpioPortA,5);
           GPIO_PinOutClear(gpioPortA,5);
       }

    // Enable receive data valid interrupt
    USART_IntEnable(USART0, USART_IEN_RXDATAV);







  }
}
```

Comment: "I dont get live stream of small bits. Instead i get a large delay and a huge block of data" I can't be sure but it sounds to me like you may need to flush the output buffer.. Also please specify in your question that it relates to C programming.

Comment: How often does the mainloop run, i.e. at what rate are those packets transmitted? How much of a delay is 10000 loops of GPIO pin setting? At what rate does the CPU run? But yes, @Vinzent could be right. This is not any more about embedded programming even, as there's too many variables here - how Matlab buffers the data, how Windows buffers the data, how the FTDI USB driver buffers data, how the USB stack buffers data, how the FTDI chip itself buffers data in its FIFO, etc..

Comment: Hello Justme, I think the delay is 10 seconds,which is defined in the serial object of the MATLAB.Its a setting which says if you dont see \n terminator after 10 seconds the show everyshing you got so far.

Comment: Too little information, but my gut feeling says you are experiencing the effects of buffered I/O from your operating system. Make sure you access the device unbuffered.

Comment: you say that windows is buffering the data coming from the FTDI cable ?
How can i disable it?
Thanks.

Comment: The callback worked before when i send a single commands Matlab recived them fine.
the problem starts when i send all the time its stops reacting to \n

Comment: "The callback worked before when i send a single commands Matlab recived them fine. the problem starts when i send all the time its stops reacting to \n" I'm pretty much just guessing at this point but if we rule out a buffer delaying the data then another possibility could be that Matlab doesn't actually react to \n at all but instead is waiting to see an EOF (End Of File).

Comment: Hello Vinzent,how can i switch it back so if i send it a stream of bytes separated by \n byte then it will not store all of them? But will send threw when reaches \n

Comment: I meant how often the MCU sends the packet, not how long timeout Matlab code has. How long is the delay between packets?

Comment: Hello Justme,as shown in the links of uploaded photos bellow,my iterative UART transmisstion signal shown on scope is 426uS and the delay between two UART signals is 80mS.
https://ibb.co/XbNPBxj

https://ibb.co/ys12yTx